# How to merge 2 array based on value?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I want to combine two arrays into one. Here I have 2 arrays namely
`remarks` and `remark_asset`.

here are the array of **remarks**

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "type": "Text",
    "name": "Text",
    "label": "Txt L",
    "description": "Txt D",
    "filter_logic": null,
    "default": "Txt Def",
    "weight": "12",
    "required": "true",
    "created_at": "2019-12-10 18:20:37",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-10 18:20:37"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "type": "Date",
    "name": "Date",
    "label": "Date Label",
    "description": "Date DEsc",
    "filter_logic": null,
    "default": "2019-12-10",
    "weight": "12",
    "required": "false",
    "created_at": "2019-12-10 18:30:29",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-10 18:30:29"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "type": "Checkbox",
    "name": "Kotaro",
    "label": "Cex",
    "description": "cex desc",
    "filter_logic": null,
    "default": "true",
    "weight": "11",
    "required": "false",
    "created_at": "2019-12-10 18:32:13",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-10 18:32:13"
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "type": "List",
    "name": null,
    "label": "Label",
    "description": "Desc",
    "filter_logic": null,
    "default": "1,2,3,4",
    "weight": null,
    "required": "false",
    "created_at": "2019-12-30 01:46:44",
    "updated_at": "2019-12-30 01:46:44"
  }
]
```

and this is an array of remark assets

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 210,
      "asset_id": 94092,
      "remark_id": 5,
      "value": "Txt Def",
      "created_at": "2019-12-13 08:55:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-12-13 08:55:41"
    },
    {
      "id": 211,
      "asset_id": 94092,
      "remark_id": 6,
      "value": "2019-12-10",
      "created_at": "2019-12-13 08:55:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-12-13 08:55:41"
    },
    {
      "id": 212,
      "asset_id": 94092,
      "remark_id": 7,
      "value": "true",
      "created_at": "2019-12-13 08:55:41",
      "updated_at": "2019-12-13 08:55:41"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 213,
      "asset_id": 94093,
      "remark_id": 5,
      "value": "Txt Def",
      "created_at": "2019-12-13 09:00:16",
      "updated_at": "2019-12-13 09:00:16"
    },
    {
      "id": 214,
      "asset_id": 94093,
      "remark_id": 6,
      "value": "2019-12-10",
      "created_at": "2019-12-13 09:00:16",
      "updated_at": "2019-12-13 09:00:16"
    },
    {
      "id": 215,
      "asset_id": 94093,
      "remark_id": 7,
      "value": "true",
      "created_at": "2019-12-13 09:00:16",
      "updated_at": "2019-12-13 09:00:16"
    }
  ]
]
```

And my expectated output is like this:

```
[
 {
    "Txt L": "Txt Def",
    "Date Label": "2019-12-10",
    "Cex": "true",
    "Label": null
  }
]
```

#### Explanation

In the output array, the key of the array is the `label` of the `remarks` array. The *value* of that key is the data of the `value` key found in the said `asset` array. The join is made by `assets.remarks_id == remarks.id`

So the key displayed will be dynamic. How can I merge the two arrays in that way? So the value part must match the `id` of the remark, for example
an asset `value` is `"Txt Def":` and that has the same `remarks_id` as the `id` where `label` is `"Txt L":`

And this is my code :

```
$getData = $data->get()->take(10);
$remark = Remark::all();
$remarkAsset = RemarkAsset::all();

/* ------------------------------ REMARK ASSET ------------------------------ */
$resultRemarkAsset = array();
foreach ($remarkAsset as $dataRemark) {
    $resultRemarkAsset[$dataRemark['asset_id']][] = $dataRemark;
}
$remarkAssetValue = array_values($resultRemarkAsset); 

//result
```

Comment: ok. All clear. Did you try anything so far that is not working? We will gladly help you with that. But no one ( hopefully ) will write the whole code for you.

Comment: wait, I will edit my post

Comment: Shouldn't the output have two objects instead of one? One by `asset_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You could first create a map (associated array) keyed by the remark id, so you can do a fast look up by that id.

At the same time initialise the result object, so it has all the labels as keys (with `null` as value)

Then visit all the asset records and find the entry in the above map by remark id. Use the found label to update the result object.

I have named the two input arrays `$remarks` and `$assets`:

```
// Create a map keyed by remark id, and create a template object:
$template = [];
foreach($remarks as $remark) {
    $map[$remark['id']] = $remark;
    $template[$remark['label']] = null;
}

$results = [];
foreach($assets as $assetArray) {
    $result = $template; // copy the template
    // For each asset entry find the label via the map:
    foreach($assetArray as $asset) {
        $id = $asset['remark_id'];
        if (isset($map[$id])) {
            $remark = $map[$id];
            $result[$remark['label']] = $asset['value'];
        }
    }
    $results[] = $result;
}
```

After this has run, `$results` will have this content for the sample data you have given:

```
[{
   "Txt L":"Txt Def",
   "Date Label":"2019-12-10",
   "Cex":"true",
   "Label":null
},{
   "Txt L":"Txt Def",
   "Date Label":"2019-12-10",
   "Cex":"true",
   "Label":null
}]
```

It has two objects, one for each sub array in the `$assets` variable. If only one object was expected, then just change the final loop so it puts everything in the same `$result` object:

```
$results = [];
$result = $template; // copy the template before the loop
foreach($assets as $assetArray) {
    // For each asset entry find the label via the map:
    foreach($assetArray as $asset) {
        $id = $asset['remark_id'];
        if (isset($map[$id])) {
            $remark = $map[$id];
            $result[$remark['label']] = $asset['value'];
        }
    }
}
$results[] = $result; // There will now only be one entry in the output
```